# Merge two dataframes based on latitude and longitude

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a dataframe which came from shapefile processing and it is like this below:

```
id=c(0,0)
long<-c(140.9619,140.9626   )
lat<-c(-35.79979,-35.77946)
order<-c(1,2)
hole<-c(FALSE,FALSE)
piece<-c(1,1)
group<-c(0.1,0.1)

dtshp<-data.frame(id,long,lat,order,hole,piece,group)
```

I also have the dataframe whose values I want to use for creating a choropleth map based on the pop.

```
Town<-c("WATSONIA","NORTH MELBOURNE","MOONEE PONDS")
Latitude<-c("-37.71610","-37.80040","-37.76010")
Longitude<-c("145.0804","144.9544","144.9228")
pop<-c(1232131,213312,342344)
dt<-data.frame(Town,Latitude,Longitude,pop)
```

So Im lookinf for a way to merge or combine those 2 datasets into one in order then to so something like:

```
map <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = Vic, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = pop)


map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and making the following change to your `dt` data frame to make your Latitude and Longitude be numeric.

```
Town<-c("WATSONIA","NORTH MELBOURNE","MOONEE PONDS")
Latitude<-c(-37.71610,-37.80040,-37.76010)
Longitude<-c(145.0804,144.9544,144.9228)
pop<-c(1232131,213312,342344)
dt<-data.frame(Town,Latitude,Longitude,pop)

Vic = dt%>%
  full_join(dtshp, by = c("Latitude" = "lat", "Longitude" = "long"))
```

You will have to decide if you want to use `full_join`, `left_join`, or `right_join`.